# Как в этом случае поставить запятую: Перед тем, как или перед тем как

Tags: недопустимая-метка, пунктуация

Как ставятся знаки препинания в составом союзе "перед тем как" в данном случае: 
"Чтобы выжать больше сока из апельсина, перед тем как разрезать, покатайте его по столу"

Comment: @Надя, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Запятая ставится перед союзом( не внутри!)  после всей придаточной части, если она предшествует главной.
В вашем случае запятая внутри союза не ставится. 
Правильно: Чтобы выжать больше сока из апельсина, перед тем как разрезать, покатайте его по столу"

> Полный академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Д.Э. Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: Орфография. Пунктуация.